# How do you trigger heroic public events and what is different?

Tags: destiny-2

There are multiple types of public events and some only at specific locations on the different worlds but all of them have a certain trigger to change them into heroic difficulty versions. I know that these are tougher with additional tasks needed to be completed and a better chance for rewards.

But how do you trigger each specific event into it's heroic version?
And what are the added objectives that must be completed for the new difficulty?

Comment: @n_palum I know for certain it is not random. The Fallen servitor event will become heroic if you kill the 3 smaller servitors before they disappear or before killing the main servitor, this makes the main boss harder. And the Fallen walker public event that's similar to that of Destiny 1, will become heroic by using the arc charges to open up the 3 weapon caches containing scorch cannons near the walker before killing it, this causes a second walker to spawn. But the other event triggers and what changes about them I'm uncertain.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Fallen Glimmer Event

Destroy all three Glimmer nodes. All three must be destroyed. A secondary event will be triggered where you defend a point against waves of enemies.

## Fallen Ether Event

Destroy all smaller servitors before eliminating the large one. The large servitor will be buffed and much harder to kill.

## Spider Tank Event

Eliminate all three force fields using arc charges (two per field), which drop in sets of three when the weak point is exposed on the tank. A second tank will spawn once the heroic level is triggered.

## Witches Ritual Event

Stand within the hex circles during the event and shoot the two crystals on either side of the portal. A Knight will spawn in addition to the Wizards.

## Vex Construction Event

Active three plates by standing on them during the event. Many additional enemies will spawn in addition to a hydra.

## Cabal Extraction Event

Begin to capture the drill. At 50 percent complete, a Cabal Thresher will spawn - destroy it. If it isn't destroyed before it leaves, it will spawn again around 75 percent. Once the Cabal Thresher is destroyed, a Cabal Excavator Unit will appear.

## Taken Event

Stepping into and then out of the smaller blights will give you a 5 second buff called Blight Receding. The buff allows you to damage the main blight which when destroyed triggers the heroic version and spawns a large taken leader.

## Cabal Injection Rig

The Cabal drop an enormous rig into an area, as you’re fighting but before you kill the Infiltrator Valus, look for the open heat vents on the rig. They’ll open in phases — three at the top, three in the middle, then one on the bottom — as you destroy them.

Once you trigger the Heroic Public Event, a Cabal Centurion will appear. He’s your new objective. Kill him to receive your big reward.

## Mercury Vex event

Kill Vex and then destroy the four portals as normal. Once you are launched the first island off the side of the map destroy that portal as well but do not leave the island yet (as this can only be done at the first island you are sent to). At the back end of the island a prism will appearing float in the air. Destroy it and a platform will appear, do this two more times each time adding another prism to be destroyed. Once you get to the top of the island structure you just capture the Vex plate to start the Heroic version of the event.

Once the portal on the other island is destroyed, go to the middle of the area and damage the Gatelord as usual. At about 66% and 33% health, he will get an invulnerability shield. When this happens a Major Vex will spawn at one end of the middle area. Kill it, and dunk the orb in the area above the Gatelord (using the jump pads just outside the middle area makes this quick). This will bring the Gatelord's shield down and you can continue damaging him.

(Note that as of this writing, this public event is buggy: if you have triggered the Heroic version, but kill the Gatelord before his invulnerability shield is brought up twice, you will only get normal rewards for the event, not the Heroic rewards.)

Comment: The taken event requires you to kill the main blight by getting a "blight receding" buff from standing inside the smaller ones.

Answer (score 3):

*There is one event missing from the list above:*

**Cabal Injection Rig**

The Cabal drop an enormous rig into an area, as you’re fighting but before you kill the **Infiltrator Valus**, look for the open heat vents on the rig. They’ll open in phases — three at the top, three in the middle, then one on the bottom — as you destroy them.

Once you trigger the Heroic Public Event, a Cabal Centurion will appear. He’s your new objective. Kill him to receive your big reward.

*Also, to add the info from VanBuzzKill's comment:*

**Taken Blight**

During each of the three waves, pillars surrounded by force fields will appear. Walk through the force fields surrounding the pillars. When you exit, you’ll have a buff called **“Blight Receding.”** (You can see it on the lower left part of your screen.) Shoot the large Blight glob while the buff is active, which is the only time you can damage it. Repeat the process until you destroy the glob, and you’ll trigger the Heroic Public Event. This will summon a new, super-strong Taken for you to defeat.

[Source](https://www.polygon.com/destiny-2-guide-walkthrough/2017/9/7/16263480/heroic-public-events-find-trigger-earth-titan-nessus-io)

Comment: The vents open after you kill each of the orange-health-bar Psions

Comment: Added to the wiki post.